# Is there a way to order a matrix with R and then break ties later?

Tags: r

I have a matrix. For example, like this:

```
temp <- cbind(rep(1:4, 3), c(rep(1, 4), rep(3,4), rep(2, 4)))

temp

# output:
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    1
 [2,]    2    1
 [3,]    3    1
 [4,]    4    1
 [5,]    1    3
 [6,]    2    3
 [7,]    3    3
 [8,]    4    3
 [9,]    1    2
[10,]    2    2
[11,]    3    2
[12,]    4    2
```

I need to order the the first column of the matrix, and then **later** break ties using the second column.

i.e., first go to this:

```
stack_temp[order(stack_temp[,1]),]

# output:

      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    1
 [2,]    1    3
 [3,]    1    2
 [4,]    2    1
 [5,]    2    3
 [6,]    2    2
 [7,]    3    1
 [8,]    3    3
 [9,]    3    2
[10,]    4    1
[11,]    4    3
[12,]    4    2
```

and then this:

```
stack_temp[order(stack_temp[,1], stack_temp[,2]),]

# output:
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    1
 [2,]    1    2
 [3,]    1    3
 [4,]    2    1
 [5,]    2    2
 [6,]    2    3
 [7,]    3    1
 [8,]    3    2
 [9,]    3    3
[10,]    4    1
[11,]    4    2
[12,]    4    3
```

but I cannot chain inputs as `order` wants me to. That is, I cannot write `stack_temp[,1], stack_temp[,2]` within the `order` function call.

This is because for the matrix I am using, I have a vector of column indices (i.e. `c(1, 2)`), so I cannot directly write the inputs above.

How do I achieve the same effect as the single `order` call when my input is a vector of column indices?

Note: in my actual problem, I have a vector of column names, not indices, and it is of variable length (usually longer than 2).

Comment: You can use `do.call` `temp[do.call(order, as.data.frame(temp)),]`  for a subset of columns `v1 <- 1:2; temp[do.call(order, as.data.frame(temp[, v1, drop = FALSE])),]`

Comment: @akrun Ah, right, I forgot `do.call` existed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can just use `do.call` with `order` and my matrix and column names to get the desired result. Thanks to @akrun for the help.